# Rule and query Help in prolog

Tags: prolog

There are facts like :

```
student(ram, cs). // ram is student of cs branch

student(kiri,it).

student(akshay,cs).

student(sanjay,me).
```

I want to write a rule to find out the classmates in any branch AND a query to list out students in a branch say cs. Please help.

what query I had to run if i had to find classmates of akshay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two students are classmates if they are participating the same course.

`classmates(X, Y) :- student(X, A), student(Y, A), X @< Y.`

[`@</2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28@%3C%29/2) here is for suppressing duplicates. I.e it is enough to have only `(A,B)` without `(B,A)`, `(A,A)` and `(B,B)`.

```
?- classmates(X, Y).
X = akshay,
Y = ram ;
false.
```

To list out all students in a branch `cs`:

```
?- student(X, cs).
X = ram ;
X = akshay.
```

Comment: what query if i had to find classmates of akshay...?

Comment: `classmates(akshay, X).`

Answer (score 0):

this being a follow up of [this previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19722678/874024) question, let's keep on the same mood...

```
classmates(Classmates) :-
  aggregate(set(P), B^Q^(student(P,B), student(Q,B), P\=Q), Classmates).
```

yields

```
?- classmates(L).
L = [akshay, ram].
```

Comment: I think its wrong..as if suppose we have a fact student(raju,it),then it will give [akshay,ram,raju,kiri] as result but we can clearly see akshay and ram are not classmates of raju and kiri.

Comment: @Hacker688: yes, I think so.. maybe I'll delete this answer ... but consider that a classmate is simply a person that has *any* other person studying the same course. Then, apart sanjay, all other students *are* classmates. Maybe, not what you're looking for...

Comment: :ya,You are right..but raju and kiri study differnet courses from akshay and ram.hence cnt be their classmate.Becose we assume those to be classmates that study same course

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting to try to understand library(aggregate). Try to play with **quantification**, those variables with **^**